How is node v20's File class intended to be used?
Node v20 officially took the File class out of experimental, but I'm not entirely sure how it was intended to be used.
There doesn't seem to be any exports in the "fs" module that create File objects. I also couldn't find references to File objects elsewhere in the docs. There is the fs.openAsBlob(), but I don't see anything that produces an instance of the File subclass.
The reason that I want to try using this is that Files and Blobs can handle more data than what in-process memory (Buffers) can handle. This is possible, because these classes are often paged and are usally just references to the raw data in the file system rather than the raw bytes themselves (Buffers).
The idea is that they can be segmented before being loaded into in-process memory. Additionally, it's method for segmenting (Blob.slice()) can also be shorter than other methods from fs, since you don't need to respecify arguments like fd and outbuffer (from fs.read()) every time you want to manipulate the file.
For right now, I'm ok with working with fs.openAsBlob() and Blobs, but being able to work with File objects would help simplify my code as it targets both the browser and node.

You literally linked the File class documentation. Its not part of the fs module, its part of the buffer module. Files and Blobs can handle more data than what in-process memory (Buffers) can handle. This is possible, because these classes are just references to the raw data in the file system rather than the raw bytes themselves Where did you get that information?

So that's inaccurate. It is paged, but the memory they consume is often small. This allows HTML file inputs to handle large files, without killing in-process memory.
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/storage/browser/blob/README.md#summary-terminology
I'll update the post

Also, I understand that it is not part of the fs module, but that doesn't answer anything. Blob is also not part of the fs module, but there are fs APIs for creating Blobs, such as fs.openAsBlob(). The purpose of the File class is for interaction with files from the File System, so how does node intend for me to use it to interact with Files from said File System (i.e. "fs"...)?
